# Trigger bootstrap 5 modal confirmation in React

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-redux

I have this delete button here where in when you click this it suppose to show the [bootstrap confirmation modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/) that looks like this:

[image]

So I have this button here along with the html code for the modal:

```
 <button classNameName="btn btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteResortOwner" onClick={() => deleteHandler(resort._id)}>
                      DELETE
                  </button>

<div className="modal fade" id="deleteResortOwner" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="deleteResortOwnerLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div className="modal-dialog">
    <div className="modal-content">
      <div className="modal-header">
        <h5 className="modal-title" id="deleteResortOwnerLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" className="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div className="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure you want to delete this resort?</p>
      </div>
      <div className="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Not Sure</button>
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now on my `onClick` effect that will call the `deleteHandler` method:

```
  const deleteHandler = (id) => {
            dispatch(deleteResortOwner(id))
    }
```

This will of course delete the item directly without showing a confirmation modal. I used to do this like this which is a basic alert:

```
const deleteHandler = (id) => {
    if(window.confirm('Are you sure')){
        dispatch(deleteResort(id))
    }
}
```

But I need this to run like a modal not an alert. Wondering how can I attain this and still open the modal to do the confirmation instead of the `window.confirm`? This will also must delete the item if the "Yes" button on the modal was click and will simply close the modal when "Close" button was click.

Any idea how to do this? Please help.

Comment: Can you bind the deleteHandler to the "Yes" button that sits inside the modal? You can have another onClick function that simply just toggles the view of the modal but doesn't submit any data.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Mind giving me a demo code or sample code based from my code above? Sorry I am just a beginner in react.

Comment: Something like `<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => deleteHandler(resort._id)}>Yes</button>`. And make the outside button just be ```<button classNameName="btn btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteResortOwner" onClick={() => openModal(resort._id)}>
                      DELETE
                  </button>```

Comment: Also tried remove the `onClick` on the button but its not opening the modal.

Comment: It did not work. openModal not found.

Comment: You'll want to create a function for `openModal`. Something like `const openModal = (resortId) =>  { this.setState({resortId: resortId})}` You can use this state variable in the deleteHandler now like `deleteHandler(this.state.resortId)`

Comment: Can you add basic working code [here](https://react.new/)

Comment: Added the code in there Shubham Verma but its requiring dependency https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-feather-f2ll5

Answer (score -2):

Use [react-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal) NPM package and then add styles using bootstrap.
And check it's docs for more details.

Comment: This was expected. I've seen this somewhere but no thanks.